# Instantiate typescript class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to `Typescript` and started using it to play with `Ionic`. I come from a `Java` background and I'm experiencing some trouble getting accustomed to it's syntax and way of doing things. Specifically creating new object instances and getting them initialized.

Recently I came across this issue which I cannot explain. I'm sending a HTTP GET request and getting it's response in a `Javascript` `Object`.

To work with this response, I'm trying to map this `Javascript` `Object` I received to a `typescript`class of mine which I called `HttpResponse`, creating a new instance of it when I receive the response. To make things easier I created a simple fiddle which ilustrates my problem.

You can find the quick written **fiddle** [on this link](https://jsfiddle.net/z4vo5u5d/280/)

As you can see on the output, object data is there but when I invoke the `HttpResponse` it just creates an empty instance, it contains nothing, and I don't understand why it does so.

Any help appreciated! Here's the code:

```
  class HttpResponse {
    constructor(status: number = 0,
    data: string =  '',
    headers: Object =  '',
    error: string =  ''){}
}


  class Page {

      response: HttpResponse;

      retrieveData(): void {
        document.body.innerHTML += 'inside retrieveData()<br>';
        let data = {
          status: 200, data: "this is some fake data",
          headers: { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', baz: 'baz' }
        }
        document.body.innerHTML +='Data: ' + JSON.stringify(data) + '<br>';
        this.response = new HttpResponse(data.status, data.data, data.headers);
        document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(this.response);

      }

  }

 new Page().retrieveData();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the constructor of your `HttpResponse` class, you are not setting the properties of the class with the passed arguments. You can do so by using the `public` qualifier in the parameters.

```
class HttpResponse {
  constructor(public status: number = 0,
  public data: string =  '',
  public headers: Object =  '',
  public error: string =  ''){ }
}
```

See the updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4vo5u5d/281/).

Alternatively, you can declare the properties in your `class` and set them in the constructor like `this.data = data;` assignments.

Comment: hum, yes, that makes sense... I was confused by the fact that you could declare properties straight inside the constructor, but now I see clearly that you have to specify the visibility modifier (either public or private I guess) to get that working. Now thinking about it I see that I just specified normal parameters in the constructor and it was not automatically converting them into class properties...... glad you helped me see that!

Answer (score 0):

Because your `HttpResponse` does not actually have any properties. You only have constructor parameters and nothing else. If you want to automatically convert your constructor parameters into properties, you can do so by using [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties):

```
class HttpResponse {
    constructor(
    public status: number = 0,
    public data: string =  '',
    public headers: Object =  '',
    public error: string =  ''){}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Saravana, I accepted jaibatrik just because he answered first. Many thanks for helping, looking from a higher perspective I see I only declared constructor params, I was so busy thinking of this "shortcut" feature to declare class members inside the constructor that I eventually fell in a beginner's mistake (:

Answer (score 0):

You must have to declare constructor parameters using qualifiers i.e. `private` `public` `protected`

```
class HttpResponse {
    constructor(
     private status: number = 0,
     private data: string =  '',
     private headers: Object =  '',
     private error: string =  ''){}
}
```